# Why does Stack Overflow not use Content-Security-Policy HTTP header to prevent XSS attacks?

Tags: discussion, security

OWASP recommends using Content-Security-Policy HTTP header to prevent XSS attacks.

I inspected Stack Overflow HTTP requests in the browser and didn't find any Content-Security-Policy HTTP header.

Why does Stack Overflow not use this?

Is there a reason to deliberately not use `Content-Security-Policy`?

Comment: Stackoverflow escapes all problematic html tags/attributes in user input.

Comment: @dan1st Sure, but there's been countless bugs where escaping wasn't done.

Comment: @Zoe you mean the bugs escaped the developers?

Comment: Related (cross site - no pun intended): *[How is my browser protected from XSS in Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/how-is-my-browser-protected-from-xss-in-stack-snippets)*

Comment: I don't know if [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) is related or not: *"we plan to deploy Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only headers"*

Comment: I'm not sure how big of an issue not using this could be, but as a gentle reminder as a general rule it's not usually a good idea to publish security holes on meta as meta is public. If you have found a serious security hole in the Stack Exchange network, it's probably a good idea to follow the guidance from the `Security` tag description: "If you think you found a serious security vulnerability, please report it on the Security page found at https://stackexchange.com/about/security. Do not post such reports on Meta!"